# Redirecting mirrored traffic from OpenBSD

Tags: virtual-machine, openbsd, network-monitoring

I have a software router running OpenBSD and a DPI service on a VM on a separate physical machine.

I want all the passing traffic to be mirrored from the OpenBSD machine to the DPI machine online (not bulk-wise but with reasonably minimized lag).  I know of a method to tunnel `tcpdump` output via SSH to the listening host and `tcpreplay`ing it there, but it feels really hacky.

What a proper method would be for my setup?  Something tunnely perhaps like GRE mirroring?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly this could be done with a bridge.
Lets say you have incoming traffic on if1 , outgoing on if2 and you have an if3 back to back with your DPI machine and ip forwarding is enabled. 
then you could

```
ifconfig bridge0 create
ifconfig bridge0 add if1 add if2 up
ifconfig bridge0 addspan if3
```

then according to man 4 bridge

```
SPAN PORTS
     The bridge can have interfaces added to it as span ports.  Span ports
     transmit a copy of every frame received by the bridge.  This is most
     useful for snooping a bridged network passively on another host connected
     to one of the span ports of the bridge.  Span ports cannot be bridge
     members; instead, the addspan and delspan commands are used to add and
     delete span ports to and from a bridge.
```